# How do I add a attribute that contains a | into an existing xml document?

Tags: xml, vb.net

I can't seem to add a | in an attribute:

For example: 'xmleSpeedLimits.SetAttribute("ServerU|LimitBypass", "0")

It won't allow it. I get: Additional information: The '|' character, hexadecimal value 0x7C, cannot be included in a name.

I tried to escape it with no success.

My console app code is:

```
    Dim xmleUserNameRoot As XmlElement
    Dim xmleOptionElement1 As XmlElement
    Dim xmleOptionElement2 As XmlElement
    Dim xmleOptionElement3 As XmlElement
    Dim xmleOptionElement4 As XmlElement
    Dim xmleOptionElement5 As XmlElement
    Dim xmleOptionElement6 As XmlElement
    Dim xmleOptionElement7 As XmlElement
    Dim xmleOptionElement8 As XmlElement
    Dim xmleOptionElement9 As XmlElement
    Dim xmleOptionElement10 As XmlElement
    Dim xmleOptionElement11 As XmlElement
    Dim xmleOptionElement12 As XmlElement
    Dim xmleOptionElement13 As XmlElement
    Dim xmleOptionElement14 As XmlElement
    Dim xmleOptionElement15 As XmlElement
    Dim xmleOptionElement16 As XmlElement
    Dim xmleOptionElement17 As XmlElement
    Dim xmleOptionElement18 As XmlElement
    Dim xmleOptionElement19 As XmlElement
    Dim xmleOptionElement20 As XmlElement
    Dim xmleOptionElement21 As XmlElement
    Dim xmleOptionElement22 As XmlElement
    Dim xmleOptionElement23 As XmlElement

    Dim xmleIpFilterRoot As XmlElement
    Dim xmlePermissionsGroup As XmlElement
    Dim xmlePermissionRoot As XmlElement
    Dim xmleSpeedLimits As XmlElement

    Dim xmleElementPrivateFtpAcctId As XmlElement
    Dim xmleElementPrivatePassword As XmlElement
    Dim xmleElementPublicFtpAcctId As XmlElement
    Dim xmleElementPublicPassword As XmlElement

    Dim strId As String
    Dim strPrivateFtpAcctId As String
    Dim strPrivatePassword As String
    Dim strPublicFtpAcctId As String
    Dim strPublicPassword As String

    Dim docNodes As XmlNodeList

    strPrivateFtpAcctId = "55555"
    strPrivatePassword = "test5"
    strPublicFtpAcctId = "66666"
    strPublicPassword = "test6"

    ' Can be any Id.
    strId = "3"

    ' Create a new XmlDocument class, and use the Load method to load the XML file.
    Dim myXmlDocument As New XmlDocument()

    ' The XmlDocument class represents the XML document and has a Load method to load the document from a file, stream, or an XmlReader.
    ' So load in the XML file.
    myXmlDocument.Load("MyFiLeZillaforadding.xml")

    ' For starting User Name.
    xmleUserNameRoot = myXmlDocument.CreateElement("User")

    ' Create an attribute and set its value to that of the new id.
    xmleUserNameRoot.SetAttribute("Name", strId)

    ' Create a new element with an attribute and add it in to the User group.
    xmleOptionElement1 = myXmlDocument.CreateElement("Option")
    xmleOptionElement1.SetAttribute("Name", "Pass")
    xmleUserNameRoot.AppendChild(xmleOptionElement1)

    xmleOptionElement2 = myXmlDocument.CreateElement("Option")
    xmleOptionElement2.SetAttribute("Name", "Group")
    xmleUserNameRoot.AppendChild(xmleOptionElement2)

    xmleOptionElement3 = myXmlDocument.CreateElement("Option")
    xmleOptionElement3.SetAttribute("Name", "Bypass server userlimit")
    xmleUserNameRoot.AppendChild(xmleOptionElement3)

    xmleOptionElement4 = myXmlDocument.CreateElement("Option")
    xmleOptionElement4.SetAttribute("Name", "User Limit")
    xmleUserNameRoot.AppendChild(xmleOptionElement4)

    xmleOptionElement5 = myXmlDocument.CreateElement("Option")
    xmleOptionElement5.SetAttribute("Name", "IP Limit")
    xmleUserNameRoot.AppendChild(xmleOptionElement5)

    xmleOptionElement6 = myXmlDocument.CreateElement("Option")
    xmleOptionElement6.SetAttribute("Name", "Enabled")
    xmleUserNameRoot.AppendChild(xmleOptionElement6)

    xmleOptionElement7 = myXmlDocument.CreateElement("Option")
    xmleOptionElement7.SetAttribute("Name", "Comments")
    xmleUserNameRoot.AppendChild(xmleOptionElement7)

    xmleOptionElement8 = myXmlDocument.CreateElement("Option")
    xmleOptionElement8.SetAttribute("Name", "ForceSsl")
    xmleUserNameRoot.AppendChild(xmleOptionElement8)

    xmleOptionElement9 = myXmlDocument.CreateElement("Option")
    xmleOptionElement9.SetAttribute("Name", "8plus3")
    xmleUserNameRoot.AppendChild(xmleOptionElement9)

    ' Create the new "IPFilter" root.
    xmleIpFilterRoot = myXmlDocument.CreateElement("IPFilter")

    ' Add elements to the "IPFilter" root.
    xmleOptionElement20 = myXmlDocument.CreateElement("Disallowed")
    xmleIpFilterRoot.AppendChild(xmleOptionElement20)

    xmleOptionElement21 = myXmlDocument.CreateElement("Allowed")
    xmleIpFilterRoot.AppendChild(xmleOptionElement21)

    ' Add the "IPFilter" root.
    xmleUserNameRoot.AppendChild(xmleIpFilterRoot)

    ' Create the new "Permissions" group.
    xmlePermissionsGroup = myXmlDocument.CreateElement("Permissions")

    ' Create the new "Permission" root.
    xmlePermissionRoot = myXmlDocument.CreateElement("Permission")
    xmlePermissionRoot.SetAttribute("Dir", "C:\inetpub\wwwroot")

    ' Add elements to the "Permission" root.
    xmleOptionElement10 = myXmlDocument.CreateElement("Option")
    xmleOptionElement10.SetAttribute("Name", "FileRead")
    xmlePermissionRoot.AppendChild(xmleOptionElement10)

    xmleOptionElement11 = myXmlDocument.CreateElement("Option")
    xmleOptionElement11.SetAttribute("Name", "FileWrite")
    xmlePermissionRoot.AppendChild(xmleOptionElement11)

    xmleOptionElement12 = myXmlDocument.CreateElement("Option")
    xmleOptionElement12.SetAttribute("Name", "FileDelete")
    xmlePermissionRoot.AppendChild(xmleOptionElement12)

    xmleOptionElement13 = myXmlDocument.CreateElement("Option")
    xmleOptionElement13.SetAttribute("Name", "FileAppend")
    xmlePermissionRoot.AppendChild(xmleOptionElement13)

    xmleOptionElement14 = myXmlDocument.CreateElement("Option")
    xmleOptionElement14.SetAttribute("Name", "DirCreate")
    xmlePermissionRoot.AppendChild(xmleOptionElement14)

    xmleOptionElement15 = myXmlDocument.CreateElement("Option")
    xmleOptionElement15.SetAttribute("Name", "DirDelete")
    xmlePermissionRoot.AppendChild(xmleOptionElement15)

    xmleOptionElement16 = myXmlDocument.CreateElement("Option")
    xmleOptionElement16.SetAttribute("Name", "DirList")
    xmlePermissionRoot.AppendChild(xmleOptionElement16)

    xmleOptionElement17 = myXmlDocument.CreateElement("Option")
    xmleOptionElement17.SetAttribute("Name", "DirSubdirs")
    xmlePermissionRoot.AppendChild(xmleOptionElement17)

    xmleOptionElement18 = myXmlDocument.CreateElement("Option")
    xmleOptionElement18.SetAttribute("Name", "IsHome")
    xmlePermissionRoot.AppendChild(xmleOptionElement18)

    xmleOptionElement19 = myXmlDocument.CreateElement("Option")
    xmleOptionElement19.SetAttribute("Name", "AutoCreate")
    xmlePermissionRoot.AppendChild(xmleOptionElement19)

    ' Add the "Permission" root to the "Permissions" group.
    xmlePermissionsGroup.AppendChild(xmlePermissionRoot)

    ' Add the "Permissions" group.
    xmleUserNameRoot.AppendChild(xmlePermissionsGroup)

    ' Create the new "SpeedLimits" root.
    xmleSpeedLimits = myXmlDocument.CreateElement("SpeedLimits")

    '' ------------------------------------------------------------->   Can't figure out how to get the pipe in this attribute.
    xmleSpeedLimits.SetAttribute("ServerU|LimitBypass", "0")
    xmleSpeedLimits.SetAttribute("U|Limit", "10")
    xmleSpeedLimits.SetAttribute("U|Type", "0")
    xmleSpeedLimits.SetAttribute("ServerD|LimitBypass", "0")
    xmleSpeedLimits.SetAttribute("D|Limit", "10")
    xmleSpeedLimits.SetAttribute("D|Type", "0")

    ' Add elements to the "SpeedLimits" root.
    xmleOptionElement22 = myXmlDocument.CreateElement("Download")
    xmleSpeedLimits.AppendChild(xmleOptionElement22)

    xmleOptionElement23 = myXmlDocument.CreateElement("Upload")
    xmleSpeedLimits.AppendChild(xmleOptionElement23)

    ' Add the "SpeedLimits" root.
    xmleUserNameRoot.AppendChild(xmleSpeedLimits)

    ' Add the remaining to User Name="#".
    xmleElementPrivateFtpAcctId = myXmlDocument.CreateElement("PrivateFtpAccountId-" & strId)
    xmleElementPrivateFtpAcctId.InnerText = strPrivateFtpAcctId
    xmleUserNameRoot.AppendChild(xmleElementPrivateFtpAcctId)

    xmleElementPrivatePassword = myXmlDocument.CreateElement("PrivatePassword-" & strId)
    xmleElementPrivatePassword.InnerText = strPrivatePassword
    xmleUserNameRoot.AppendChild(xmleElementPrivatePassword)

    xmleElementPublicFtpAcctId = myXmlDocument.CreateElement("PublicFtpAccountId-" & strId)
    xmleElementPublicFtpAcctId.InnerText = strPublicFtpAcctId
    xmleUserNameRoot.AppendChild(xmleElementPublicFtpAcctId)

    xmleElementPublicPassword = myXmlDocument.CreateElement("PublicPassword-" & strId)
    xmleElementPublicPassword.InnerText = strPublicPassword
    xmleUserNameRoot.AppendChild(xmleElementPublicPassword)

    ' Now, need to place the whole User Name="#" group between <Users> and </Users>.
    ' Get a list of the nodes.
    docNodes = myXmlDocument.LastChild.ChildNodes()

    ' Look for the "Users" node.
    For Each node As XmlNode In docNodes
        If node.Name = "Users" Then
            ' Add the whole User Name="#" group after this last User in the "Users" node.
            node.AppendChild(xmleUserNameRoot)
        End If
    Next

    ' Save in place.
    myXmlDocument.Save("MyFiLeZillaforadding.xml")

    Console.WriteLine("The XML file was saved successfully.")
```

Regards...

Comment: The short answer is "you can't". XML has specific rules for what characters are valid parts of speech, and the rules state "alphanumerics plus hyphens". You could create an attribute `ServerU-or-LimitBypass`

Comment: I thought this is a | but it is not. Here is what I pulled from an existing XML file and need to recreate.            ' Is this a 1? Does not look like it.
        ' -<SpeedLimits ServerUlLimitBypass="0" UlLimit="10" UlType="0" ServerDlLimitBypass="0" DlLimit="10" DlType="0">

Comment: The character between U and Limit as well as the others.

Comment: When I look a that the file in Notepad, the character looks similar to an upside down L facing the other way.

Answer (score 0):

You can print ascii code (and/or the unicode) of the dubious character to make sure :

```
'following string value copy-pasted from your comment'
Dim word As String = "ServerUlLimitBypass"
For Each c As Char In word.ToCharArray()
    Console.WriteLine("{0}  U+{1:x4} {1}", c, Convert.ToInt16(c), Convert.ToInt16(c))
Next
```

Truned out that `l`'s ascii code is 108 which represents [lowercase letter of L](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-printable-characters/lowercase-letter-l-minuscule-ascii-code-108.html), means you *don't need to escape it*.